# Bash - replace escaped characters

Tags: bash, escaping

I have to replace all slashes, antislashes, single and double quotes in a variable, possibly in on pass, with their escaped version:

```
' --> \'
" --> \"
\ --> \\
/ --> \/
```

At this point, I use this to replace single quote:

```
${MYVAR//\'/\\\'}
```

But I'm stucked when I'm trying to replace slashes, antislashes, single and double quotes in one pass.

Comment: If you're trying to escape a string for use as shell input, you could try [`printf '%q' "$MYVAR"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573839/how-to-use-printf-q-in-bash) (if your bash supports it).

Comment: It's for use in a Synology NAS script: I have to send the value of a variable from bash by mail using PHP engine. Of course, PHP returns an error with nested quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed replace:

```
echo "'\"\\/" | sed "s~\(['\"\/]\)~\\\\\1~g"
```

- [short explanation of sed command](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/sed.md)
- [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

---

Edit according to the comments:

```
EXPLORE_FOLDER="/volume1/video/myMovies"
LS_LIST="$(ls --recursive "$EXPLORE_FOLDER")"
RESULT="$(sed "s~\(['\"\/]\)~\\\\\1~g" <<<"$LS_LIST")"
echo "$RESULT"
```

Or just:

```
EXPLORE_FOLDER="/volume1/video/myMovies"
RESULT="$(ls --recursive "$EXPLORE_FOLDER" | sed "s~\(['\"\/]\)~\\\\\1~g" <<<"$LS_LIST")"
echo "$RESULT"
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, but I'm a totally newbie... Where is MYVAR in you sed solution?

Comment: @Zax Like this: `echo "$MYVAR" | sed ...`

Comment: Or, better still, use a [herestring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of) to avoid creating unnecessary processes: `sed ... <<<"$MYVAR"`

Comment: @will ahem... I'm unable to make it work. I used:   `EXPLORE_FOLDER="/volume1/video/myMovies"
LS_LIST=$(ls --recursive "$EXPLORE_FOLDER")
sed "'\"\\/" | "s~\(['\"\/]\)~\\\\\1~g" <<<"$LS_LIST"
echo $LS_LIST` (LS_LIST must be emailed later).

Comment: @Zax I just updated my answer to match the example you provided.

Comment: @Pavel Thank you very much! (btw, I also found then I couldn't send too large variable as message to php, but it's another problem).